# JupyterLab viewer for static websites (e.g. jekyll)

Tags: jekyll, jupyter-lab

I use Jupyter notebooks to create posts for a jekyll based website, so I'm starting to try out JupyterLab. If I have `jekyll serve ...` running a development server, is there a way to view it *within* a JupyterLab window/panel/tab?